# Add new row before specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

My table is composed of DAYS - Monday, Tuesday .... and rows to each day.

Each day in table has ADD button

By clicking on ADD button, JS add new row to particular day (monday, tuesday etc...).

Currently, JS add new row directly inside `<tr>` element where ADD button is stored.

I would like that by click ADD button, new row is added BEFORE next `<tr class="day">` element

I have already tried: .append(), .appendTo(), .before(), .insertBefore(), any of them did not work for me.

Any ideas how to do that? --> adding new rows to the end of part of the table (or before next part of the table).

`$this` element:

```
`<a class="add_fields btn btn-primary workingday-row" data-id="70358063118960" data-fields="<tr>  <td><input label=&quot;false&quot; type=&quot;time&quot; name=&quot;teacher[working_days_attributes][0][working_hours_attributes][70358063118960][from]&quot; id=&quot;teacher_working_days_attributes_0_working_hours_attributes_70358063118960_from&quot; /></td>  <td><input label=&quot;false&quot; type=&quot;time&quot; name=&quot;teacher[working_days_attributes][0][working_hours_attributes][70358063118960][to]&quot; id=&quot;teacher_working_days_attributes_0_working_hours_attributes_70358063118960_to&quot; /></td>  <td>    <input type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; name=&quot;teacher[working_days_attributes][0][working_hours_attributes][70358063118960][_destroy]&quot; id=&quot;teacher_wor`king_days_attributes_0_working_hours_attributes_70358063118960__destroy&quot; />    <a class=&quot;remove_record&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;>Remove wokring Hour</a>  </td></tr" href="#">Add Working Hour</a>
```

Jquery part of code:

```
$(this).closest('tr').append($(this).data('fields').replace('booking_booking_working_days_working_day_id', time));
```

HTML:

```
    <tr class="day">
      <td>
        Monday
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HERE IS MY ADD BUTTON</td>
      <tr>
         HERE ARE NEWLY ADDED FIELDS
      </tr>
    </tr>
      HERE I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE NEWLY ADDED FIELDS (probably inside another <tr></tr>)
    <tr class="day">
      <td>
        Tuesday
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Did you try `.after()` and `.insertAfter()`?

Answer (score 0):

`.append(html)` inserts the html inside the element it's called on. Instead you can use `.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', html)`. The key here is 'after end which tells the html be inserted [after the targetElement itself.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)